# Retrieving data from appengine database and displaying it in a form

Tags: google-app-engine

Im working on a CMS for appengine using python, I have a form page much like how wordpress works where you enter a Title, content and other meta data for the page. Lets say this is AddPage

Once the page is saved the data is stored and a link is shown on the article index page. Just like wordpress when you click on posts. What Im trying to do is once a link is clicked on the index page the user is redirected to a page which is exactly like the AddPage but it already has data filled in ready for editing.

How would I do this am I missing something:

```
class EditPageHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def get(self, articleID):
        page_details = db.GqlQuery("SELECT * FROM TitlePage WHERE key_name = '" + articleID + "'" )
    pageDetails_list = page_details.fetch(10)
    template = jinja_environment.get_template('templates/editcourse.html')
    self.response.out.write(template.render({'page_details':pageDetails_list}))
```

the html template would display something like:

```
<input id="author" type="text" name="author" maxlength="120" value="{{ page_details.Author }}">
```

Im not getting any errors and this does not work so something is not right here:

I have also tried outputting it like so:

Still nothing any help please.

Comment: is there an Author field on your TitlePage model?

Comment: Alos, be careful about code injection when building your gql query. Try db.GqlQuery("SELECT * FROM TitlePage WHERE key_name=:1", articleID) or TitlePage.gql("WHERE key_name=:1", articleID) is even easier

Comment: Try logging the query you are executing and the parameter articleID. Then execute that same query in the datastore viewer and check if it returns something. Can you post the configuration of your app, specifically the routing part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to solve this the approach I was using above was all wrong instead what worked was this:

```
class EditPageHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def get(self, articleID):
          page_details = TitlePage.get_by_key_name(articleID)
          template = jinja_environment.get_template('templates/editcourse.html')
          self.response.out.write(template.render({'detail':page_details}))
```

and as for the html I just did:

```
<input id="author" type="text" name="author" value="{{ detail.Author }}">
```

And it worked :)

Thanks to gwynhowell for the suggestion to improve the code I made the changes and many thanks to you Sebastian Kreft for the suggestion that got me moving in the right track.

Answer (score 0):

Buddy, as per you posted code, in that it seems clearly `pageDetails_list = page_details.fetch(10)` will returns a list/array.

But in template side, you doing stuff like 
`<input id="author" type="text" name="author" maxlength="120" value="{{ page_details.Author }}">` 
which actually wrong as here **page_details** expecting object. but you passing there list.
so it should be in for loop like this,

```
{% for page_detail in page_details %}
   //do stuff..
{% endfor %}
```

I think, this should work for you.

Comment: I did try this but it doesnt work either? Any other suggestions?